# How can thread function call using thread identifier using POSIX threads?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I'm new to posix threads. I'm working on a project in which one component upon initialization creates all posix threads. The other component has to request pool manager if there is any thread free. If free, pool manager returns thread handler and the other component handover its data to that thread handler. I've two questions:

1. Upon initialization, creation of threads means pthread_create() function is called. So, thread executes its routine mentioned in pthread_create() and exit. How can pool manager identify free thread?
2. If thread waiting in its routine for its data, then how can other component handover its data to thread using thread handler.

Comment: Read more about pthreads and its synchronization (mutexes, condvars, rwlocks, barriers). You could create a fixed number of threads waiting for some task queue to change.

Comment: You seem to be of the impression the thread in a pool are strictly client code; *they're generally not*. Pools usually have their own thread procs that are tasked with running *something*. That something is usually from the pool client that pushes the its own proc and some argument data into a queue, then lets the pool manage how to distribute the task to the threads managed by the pool. The thread procs in the pool are coded to synchronize how to safely extract queue data, perform the user task, and return to the pool for more work. Books and articles are written on the subject; get one.

Comment: Search for the term "thread pool" online. Basically, creating a thread is like hiring a person. A thread pool hires a bunch of people but doesn't give them any work. When you then ask the thread pool for a free worker, the worker gets assigned some work. When a thread finishes and exits, it's like firing the worker. However, in the thread pool context, they only report back to the pool manager and wait for their next task. This avoids the overhead of starting and stopping threads (hiring and firing workers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you use mutexes and condition variables and some shared memory structure.
For example, you would create an array, a mutex and a condition variable.  Then your worker thread in the pool would:

1. lock the mutex
2. do a wait on the condition variable (mutex gets released automatically for you)
3. once wait returns it means cond var got signaled (and mutex is locked again for you)
4. remove the piece of work from the array
5. unlock the mutex (or go back to (2)

In the client thread which wants to submit jobs to the pool:

1. lock the mutex
2. add work to the array
3. signal the condition variable

There are lots of tutorials about this, e.g. 
https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarCreation